# Azure Devops Return Variable from Template

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to return a variable from a template so I can use that as a parameter for other templates?

I have a yml file that looks something like this (actual names redacted).

```
  - stage: A
    jobs:
      - template: a.yml
        parameters:
          environment: foo
          group: bar
      - template: b.yml
        parameters:
          dependsOn: a
          environment: foo
          group: bar
      - template: c.yml
        parameters:
          dependsOn: a
          environment: foo
          group: bar
```

Each template is a deployment.

I want `a.yml` to set a variable, then for that to be returned so that I could use that variable as a parameter for the other 2 templates. How can I return a variable using 'a.yml'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `depands` to pass parameters between two templates just as passing parameters between stages. Here is an example. I use `environment` as the parameters to be passed between a.yml and b.yml.

a.yml:

```
parameters:
  environment: foo
  group: bar

jobs:
- job: deployA
  variables:
    env: ${{ parameters.environment }}
  steps:
  - pwsh: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=env;isOutput=true]$($env:ENV)"
    name: outputVar
```

b.yml:

```
parameters:
  dependsOn: a
  environment: foo
  group: bar

jobs:
- job: deployB
  dependsOn: deployA
  steps:
  ...
```

pipeline.yml:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: A
    jobs:
    - template: a.yml
      parameters:
        environment: Test
    - template: templateB.yml
      parameters:
        environment: $[dependencies.deployA.outputs['outputVar.env']]
```

Comment: What if templateA and templateB are in different stages - so dependencies are not written on the jobs but written on the stage level? :)